# When loading custom font after refresh of page, other font type is displaing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I changed my page title font to custom font.
When I refresh a page especially at IE I see other font type for a moment and then my custom font load.
How to change this to show only a proper font type ? (this looks really bad).

```
@font-face {font-family: "ISOCT3"; 
src: url("https://example_page.com/ISOCT3/6d585d4b2c76dabcf084d51d2e9c87e1.eot"); 
src: url("https://example_page.com/ISOCT3/6d585d4b2c76dabcf084d51d2e9c87e1_2.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
url("https://example_page.com/ISOCT3/6d585d4b2c76dabcf084d51d2e9c87e1.woff2") format("woff2"), 
url("https://example_page.com/ISOCT3/6d585d4b2c76dabcf084d51d2e9c87e1_2.woff") format("woff"), 
url("https://example_page.com/ISOCT3/6d585d4b2c76dabcf084d51d2e9c87e1.ttf") format("truetype"), 
url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/6d585d4b2c76dabcf084d51d2e9c87e1.svg#ISOCT3") format("svg"); }
```

```
#header .header_logo {
    font-family: ISOCT3;
    font-size: 38px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 28px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    max-width: 80%;
    color: #b8860b;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    float: center;
}
```

```
<div class="header_logo">
                <a href="https://example_page.com/" style="text-decoration: none;">
                PAGE NAME
                </a>
            </div>
```

Comment: Normal behavior. But you could hide the entire page until it's ready, then show it. By hide I mean draw something else on top of it.

Comment: Do you have any code example ?

Comment: Search for "preoloader example"

Comment: did you include your font.css within the <head> element? I normally get that behavior when i have my fonts loaded with .js when they are added at the bottom of the page. That's when I have bundled everything using webpack

Comment: Mabe the Web Font Loader will be helpful in yours case. Checok it on GitHub. It could solve urs font loading problem. [Here is link to github with useful documentation ](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader)